# Pandas interpret column as dataframe instead of column and returns error

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am working with a dataframe that unfortunately I cannot share here. I am running the following command for all my columns

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(type(df[col]))
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors = 'coerce')
```

but I get the following error

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-40-2dc7ceea54d2> in <module>()
>      27 for col in df.columns:
>      28     print(type(df[col]))
> ---> 29     df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors = 'coerce')
>      30 
>      31 
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py in
> to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
>     118         values = np.array([arg], dtype='O')
>     119     elif getattr(arg, 'ndim', 1) > 1:
> --> 120         raise TypeError('arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series')
>     121     else:
>     122         values = arg
> 
> TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

I believe because Python is interpreting my columns as dataframes. In fact, the command print(type(df[col])) returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I have been using python for a while and this is the first time I see this kind of issue! What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. One of the columns had a duplicate. If Pandas see two columns with the same name it interprets them as a pandas dataframe.